# JavaScript Making independent functions work without defining new

Tags: javascript, function, object

I have code like this:

```
function Food(type) {
  this.type = type;
  this.timesEaten = 0;
}

Food.prototype.eat = function() { // Dependent function
  this.timesEaten++;
}

Food.prototype.pasta = function() { // In-dependent function
  return new Food("pasta")
}
```

So, I want to be able to use the pasta function without defining a new food, like this:

```
var pasta = Food.pasta()
```

Buut, that doesn't work, you have to do like this:

```
var pasta = new Food().pasta()
```

Well "Food.pasta()" does work if you set up Food like this:

```
var Food = {
  pasta: function() {
    return {type: pasta};
  }
}
```

But then new Food won't work, which means I'll have to use "return {type: pasta}".

I wonder, is there any way to create a Food that can be both dependent and independent?

Comment: Perhaps something for you, http://jsbin.com/taqulivo/1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function Food(type) {
  this.type = type;
  this.timesEaten = 0;
}

Food.prototype.eat = function() { // Dependent function
  this.timesEaten++;
}

Food.pasta = function() { // In-dependent function
  return new Food("pasta")
}
```

`Food.prototype` functions are only available for objects of `Food`, while for `Food.pasta` `Food` is only a namespace object.

Usage:

```
Food.pasta();
```

Answer (score 6):

A method like your `.pasta()` method that does not operate on any instance data is called a static method.  You don't want it on the prototype because the prototype will only be in the lookup chain on an instantiated object (after creating an actual `Food` object by doing `new Food()`).

Instead, for a static method you can put it on the constructor function itself like this:

```
Food.pasta = function() {
    return new Food("pasta");
}
```

The, you can call it like this:

```
var pasta = Food.pasta();
```

---

It's useful to remember that in javascript, Functions are objects too so they can have properties/methods and when you're looking for a place to put static functions or data that don't belong to a particular instantiated object or need to be called on a particular instantiated object, the Constructor object is often a good place to put them.

Comment: Why did you post this when bbuecherl already posted the same answer?

Comment: @Murplyx Their answers were posted 50 seconds apart. I imagine jfriend was already well into working on an answer when bbuecherl submitted his/hers. Also, jfriend's answer contains considerably more explanation than bbuecherl's does.

Comment: It's surprising that they both where posted under 6 minutes after I posted mine.

Comment: @Murplyx - when I wrote my answer, there were no answers showing.

Comment: Why do you keep it now then?

Comment: @Murplyx - Does my answer not include some explanation that is not covered in the other answer?  StackOverflow isn't a first-come first served, winner take all system.  I wrote an original answer (didn't copy anyone) and it's up to the readers to decide which answer to vote for and you which answer to accept.  In fact, some of what bbuecherl wrote isn't even correct.  `Food` is a Function object.  I'm not sure why bbuecherl called it a "namespace object".

Comment: I think I got my Food served pretty well from bbuecherl.

Comment: @Murplyx - that's good.  No problem with that.  I just don't know why you're asking me to remove my answer?

Comment: Well, you can keep it if you want, but I'm not hungry anymore.